# Hiding a div using a asp.net checkbox oncheckchanged event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I am trying to hide a div using asp.net checkbox server control. I added a onclick javascript code for the server control but it seems not working....any suggestions?

```
    function hideDiv(obj) {

        if (obj.checked==true) {
            document.getElementById("divMap").style.visibility=true
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("divMap").style.visibility = false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function hideDiv(obj) {
    if (obj.checked==true) {
        document.getElementById("divMap").style.display='block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("divMap").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

or you can use jquery

```
function hideDiv(obj) {
    if (obj.checked) {
        $("#divMap").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#divMap").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: how can put it in asp.net? <asp:CheckBox ID="chkShowAllOnMap" Text="Show all results on map" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onClick="hideDiv(this)" />

Answer (score 2):

This could also be achieved server side.

Markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox id="chk" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
<div id="div" runat="server"></div>
```

C#:

```
protected void chk_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    switch ((sender.checked)) {
        case true:
            div.Visible = false;
            break;
        case false:
            div.Visible = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below code instead of

```
document.getElementById("divMap").style.visibility = false
document.getElementById("divMap").style.visibility=true  




document.getElementById("divMap").style.display='none'
     document.getElementById("divMap").style.display='block'
```

Answer (score 0):

To access and use a server side control in asp.net you have to use it's client id (ClientID) property.

```
function hideDiv(obj) {

    if (obj.checked==true) {
        document.getElementById("<%=YourControlID.ClientID %>").style.visibility=true
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("<%=YourControlID.ClientID %>").style.visibility = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform operation on server control from javascript user  “<%=control Name .ClientID%>”

```
 function hideDiv(obj) {

        if (obj.checked==true) {
            document.getElementById('<%= divMap.ClientID%>').style.display = 'Block';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('<%= divMap.ClientID%>').style.display = 'None';
        }
    }
```